# How to create custom annotation for private methods to retry on particular exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-retry

I am working on spring boot project. @Retryable is not working on private methods due to proxy. I like to create a custom annotation that helps private method to retry on particular exception like how spring-retry works on public methods. I went through multiple sites but didn't get proper solution.